# If $H \leq G$ and $H \subset Z(G)$, the center of $G$, is $H \trianglelefteq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is probably a very dumb question. Is it true that, in general, if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$, and $H \subset Z(G)$, the center of $G$, does it follow that $H$ is normal in $G$?

What I know so far that could potentially be useful:

- $Z(G)$ is normal in $G$.
- $H$ is normal in $G \Leftrightarrow gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $g \in G$.

This is part of an intermediate step for a homework problem.

Comment: Not only is $H$ normal in $G$, it is central in $G$.

Comment: Haven't heard that term before.

Comment: Elements in $H$ commute with all of $G$. So $ghg^{-1}=h\,\,\, \forall \ h\in H, g\in G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. As a hint for how to prove it, let $h \in H$ and use the fact that $h \in Z(G)$ to simplify $ghg^{-1}$.

Comment: So if $h \in H$ and $h \in Z(G)$, then $ghg^{-1} = gg^{-1}h = h \in H$. Wow, that was easy. Many thanks. I'll mark yours as best answer once I get the chance.

Answer (score 4):

This can be understood intuitively with [**group actions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action). Say $G$ acts on a set $X$:

- A subset $Y\subseteq X$ is pointwise fixed if $gy=y$ for all $g\in G$.
- A subset $Y\subseteq X$ is setwise fixed if $gY:=\{gy:y\in Y\}=Y$ for all $g\in G$.

The group $G$ acts on itself by conjugation. Then:

- A subset $H\subseteq G$ is **central** if $~[G,H]=1 ~~\Leftrightarrow~H\subseteq Z(G)~ \Leftrightarrow~  H$ is pointwise fixed.
- A subset $H\subseteq G$ is **normal** if it is setwise fixed.

For general group actions, pointwise fixed is much stronger than ($\Rightarrow$) setwise fixed. Therefore we may directly conclude that central ($H\subseteq Z(G)$) implies normal ($H\trianglelefteq G$) in this case.

Comment: I'll be learning about group actions in about a week. Thank you!

Comment: not anyone needs a sword to cut the flowers

Comment: @janmarqz You've never played Zelda have you? For me, group actions are absolutely intuitive $-$ they can be "seen" and they "fit inside my head" $-$ whereas element-chasing is a mindless and tedious chore. Thus it makes sense for me to prefer my answer.

Comment: oh yes, agree, by now we are embedded into [ http://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/2014/01/28/permutational-wreath-product/ ]

Comment: @anon: see? more upvotes didn't mean a √

Comment: @janmarqz I was not aiming for nor under the impression this answer would be the best-fitted for OP. Wasn't even aiming for the most upvotes. I simply wished to spread the gospel of group actions.

Answer (score 1):

Since any $h\in H\le Z(G)$ then $hx=xh$ for all $x\in G$, so $xhx^{-1}=h\in H$ i.e. 
$$xHx^{-1}\subseteq H,$$
which is enough to warranty that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I think about it. If you are in the center, you commute with everything. If $H$ is normal, you have to be able to conjugate an element $h \in H$ by $g \in G$ and land back in $H$, in other words $ghg{-1} \in H$. But $h$ is in the center, so you have $ghg^{-1}=gg^{-1}h=h$ which is certainly in $H$. So $H$ is normal.